# How to make a message box to close the running process?

Tags: autoit

When the process is running I need a message box with "Cancel" and "Proceed" buttons:

- Cancel = stop script (exit from script).
- Proceed = kill the process
  to continue the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MsgBox()` has some [predefined button combinations](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MsgBox.htm) (first parameter "Flag"):

```
0 OK  
1 OK and Cancel 
2 Abort, Retry, and Ignore 
3 Yes, No, and Cancel 
4 Yes and No 
5 Retry and Cancel 
6 Cancel, Try Again, Continue

$x = MsgBox(1, "Proceed?", "Want to continue?")
ConsoleWrite($x & @CRLF)
If $x = 1 Then ConsoleWrite("continuing..." & @CRLF)
If $x = 2 Then ConsoleWrite("exiting..." & @CRLF)
```

If you don't want to use them, you will have to build your own GUI instead.

Answer (score 1):

As Stephan said Autoit does not have built-in functionality like that.

So you have three options:

- adapt your script to one of the predefined ones, such as `MessageBox($MB_OKCANCEL, "", "Click 'Ok' to kill process")` or more relevant but with extra button: `$MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE`
- use `GuiCreate()` to make your own message box
- download and use someone else's code that does what you want, such as: [Melba23's ExtMsgBox](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/109096-extended-message-box-new-version-2-aug-18) - those are called UDFs and are generally found on [AutoIt forums](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/)